# TexStudio next placeholder shortcut not working

Tags: texstudio

I've recently started using `TexStudio` and decided to change the default next placeholder shortcut from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. The change is correctly listed in the shortcuts configuration sub menu where it used to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> but the shortcut no longer works. I've tried restarting TexStudio since the change but that hasn't helped.

Do any `TexStudio` users know what could be causing this problem? I find the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> shortcut quite frustrating so I'd really like to be able to change it if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty much in the right direction, but you were unhappy with your particular shortcut choice. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is a common shortcut to change the next open Tab (as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does for open Windows). I'm not sure if this is set within TeXstudio, or at the system level. But apparently, we cannot steal it from its original function (that's not quite true, see update below).

But you can choose another key combination, of course. I have my settings as (of course, what is pertinent here will depend on your keyboard layout):

> Previous placeholder = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>
>
> Previous placeholder or character = "none"
>
> Previous placeholder or one word left = "none"
>
> Next placeholder = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>
>
> Next placeholder or character = "none"
>
> Next placeholder or one word right = "none"

Now, if you, like me, are annoyed by this particular shortcut because it steals the very common behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd> to navigate between words in the editor, you might also want to set:

> Move cursor left (1 word) = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
>
> Move cursor right (1 word) = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

**Update**: (courtesy of @Troy) As it turns out the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is indeed defined within TeXstudio as the additional shortcut for "Next document" (in "Menus" -> "View"). If you remove this additional shortcut for "Next document", you can then use it for "Next placeholder" instead, as you originally intended.

Comment: Btw, thank you for your question. I was haunted by this shortcut for some time, but hadn't stopped to fix it.

Comment: Nice +1. To add on, Ctrl+Tab is the additional shortcut for "Next document".  Just deleting that shortcut map should do the trick as well I think?

Comment: @Troy, oh that was screaming at me and I couldn't find it! I did try! And even with your hint it still eluded me. Actually TS is somewhat clumsy in this particular configuration tab. It is indeed hard to know what is already taken. Well, short of expanding and reading the whole list. Thanks!